# Hide Orbit Slider Images until all are loaded

Tags: jquery, css, image, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm using Foundation 5's Orbit slider and it's working fine, but when the page initially loads the images flash and then load in to the slider. Is there a way to hide the images until they are all loaded?

**HAML**

```
.row
  .medium-4.large-5.columns
    %ul.example-orbit{"data-orbit" => ""}
      - Cms::File.for_category('founder-carousel').each do |file|
        %li
          .slide= image_tag(file.file.url)
          .orbit-caption= file.description
```

Comment: just a quick guess..keep the images or orbit's visibility hidden...and make them visible on the Page load event i.e. when all images are loaded up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orbit has onReady event. You can set default class for it with `visibility:hidden`(this wey it won't be visible but still will be part of the document flow) and change it to the `visibility:visible` when it's ready.

```
$("#myOrbit").on("ready.fndtn.orbit", function(event) {
  ... //your code here
});`
```

If it won't help you can add `onload` to the `img` tags with counter. Show Orbit when all of them loaded.